# Post request to specific API with file

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I'm trying to make a post request to API:

```
access_token = '71e89e8af02206575b3b4ae80bf35b6386fe3085af3d4085cbc7b43505084482'
url_base = "https://dev-100-api.huntflow.ru/"


url_resume = '{0}account/6/upload'.format(url_base)
headers_resume = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'X-File-Parse': 'true',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(access_token),
}
files = {
    'file': open('Глибин Виталий Николаевич.doc', 'rb'),
}


resume1 = requests.post(url_resume, headers=headers_resume, files=files)

print(resume1.text)
```

And output is: {"errors": [{"type": "server_error"}]}

The documentation says:

```
POST /account/{account_id}/upload
```

To upload a file send a request multipart/form-data with a file in parameter file.

To make sure that the file will be processed by the system of field recognition, one has to pass a header X-File-Parse: true. In this case the response will contain the fields text, photo, fields.

Example request:

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
    -H "X-File-Parse: true" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" \
    -F "file=@resume.pdf" \
    https://api.huntflow.ru/account/<account_id>/upload
```

Help me, please! What's wrong?

Comment: Since it's `server_error`, try to change file name, maybe the server couldn't resolve non-ascii characters or spaces.

Comment: Looks like you made the request ok but the server didn't like what you sent it (or is broken). We're unlikely to be able to help with errors specific to that API. Maybe check the docs or contact the provider.

Comment: @SimonN I updated the question...

Comment: @Kasper I updated the question...

Comment: did you tried to change file name? try to make it alphanumeric and without spaces for example  `filename.txt` (English characters with numbers)

Comment: @Kasper the same :(

Comment: I just tried doing this `curl -X POST https://dev-100-api.huntflow.ru/account/6/upload -H "Authorization: Bearer 71e89e8af02206575b3b4ae80bf35b6386fe3085af3d4085cbc7b43505084482" -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' -H 'X-File-Parse: true' -F "file=@test.txt"` and the file uploaded successfully. Maybe you can take a hint from it

Comment: @Kasper I've already did this :) But how to do this without curl, in the requests?

Comment: I think is the problem is not from your side, it's from server side

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found this [issue](https://github.com/huntflow/api/issues/104) related to the same website you're trying to send file to it

The solution is something like follows:

```
import requests
import os
import mimetypes

token = "71e89e8af02206575b3b4ae80bf35b6386fe3085af3d4085cbc7b43505084482"
url = "https://dev-100-api.huntflow.ru/account/6/upload"

def upload_file(name, content):
    mimetypes.init()
    ext_data = os.path.splitext(name)
    if len(ext_data) > 1:
        mime_type = mimetypes.types_map.get(ext_data[len(ext_data) - 1]) or 'application/zip'
    else:
        mime_type = 'application/zip'

    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token),
        'User-Agent': 'App/1.0 (eeee@eeee.ru)',
    }
    r = requests.request(
        'POST',
        url,
        files={'file': (name, content, mime_type)},
        headers=headers,
    )
    return r.json()

print(upload_file("test.txt", "text/plain"))
```

I got the following response:

```
{'name': 'test.txt', 'url': 'https://dev-100-store.huntflow.ru/uploads/named/z/q/j/zqj0jf98dud8grbazjleyjy3ii4wrsah.txt/test.txt?s=z-pORM3y1qUVU4XhbsHKBg&e=1589632103', 'content_type': 'text/plain', 'id': 58}
```